# Nginx sni not working? Configure nginx sni to get multiple reverse proxies

Tags: nginx

I want to configure two reverse proxies with ssl that proxy pass to different applications.

```
nginx version: nginx/1.19.9
built by gcc 8.3.0 (Ubuntu 8.3.0-6ubuntu1)
built with OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --user=www --group=www --prefix=/usr/local/nginx --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_sub_module --with-stream --with-stream_ssl_module --with-openssl=/root/lnmp1.6/src/openssl-1.1.1d --with-openssl-opt='enable-weak-ssl-ciphers' --with-stream --with-stream_ssl_preread_module --with-stream_realip_module
```

I have a normal website say mysite.com, which ngnix configuration is

```
http{
...
server
    {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;
        index index.html index.htm index.php default.html default.htm default.php;
....
      }
}
```

The website works fine.
Then I add stream module to my nginx configuration.

```
events{....}
#stream module start
stream 
{
  map $ssl_preread_server_name $stream_map {
    mysite.com web;
    v2.mysite.com web2;
  }
  upstream web2 {
    server 127.0.0.1:10001; 
  }
  upstream web {
    server 127.0.0.1:10002; 
  } 
  server {
    listen 443 reuseport;
    listen [::]:443 reuseport;
    proxy_pass  $stream_map;
    ssl_preread on;
    proxy_protocol on; 
  }
}
#stream module end
http{
...
server
    {
        listen 127.0.0.1:10002 ssl http2 proxy_protocol;
        server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;
        index index.html index.htm index.php default.html default.htm default.php;
...
      }
}
```

In this case, I can't reach normal website using mysite.com anymore.
What am I missing to make this sni work?

Comment: stream does not support server_name and will listen as default, hence if you use stream on 443, your other server blocks won't work anymore. If you want to work concurrently, u need to change stream port to some other numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I split [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com) and mysite.com into two upstreams and two vhosts respectively and it works.

```
upstream web1 {
  server 127.0.0.1:10001; 
}
upstream web2 {
  server 127.0.0.1:10002; 
}
```

and in vhost part
use

```
server
  {
      listen 127.0.0.1:10001 ssl http2 proxy_protocol;
      server_name mysite.com; 
...}
server
  {
      listen 127.0.0.1:10002 ssl http2 proxy_protocol;
      server_name www.mysite.com; 
...}
```